# Explicitly set routevalues in MVC actionlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC site with a separate Area for my admin section.

Trying to set up an ActionLink with RouteValues, and it is problematic.

Here is my global for a particular page (note I have to specify the controller location for these to work):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "HomeEditStep1",
                "EditStep1",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "EditStep1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                    new string[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" }
            );
```

If I craft a link like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditStep1", "Home");
```

the link takes me to that page appropriately.  But if I add params, as needed:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditStep1", "Home", new {  id = page.PageDetailGuid.ToString() }, new { @class = "btn lightblue" });
```

Then it seems to ignore the Global and returns this, pointing to a service for some reason:
/Services/AccountService?action=EditStep1&controller=Home&id=84ac76cd-fcb0-444b-adab-c0c041a81c1a

So I need it to be /EditStep1/84ac76cd-fcb0-444b-adab-c0c041a81c1a.

I do have routes.IgnoreRoute("{service}.svc/{*pathInfo}"); defined in the global as well.

My question is, do I need to explicitly set MyProject.Web.Controllers somehow, in the routevalues?

Thanks!
Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your definition of the route, you need to include the parameters, give something like this a try

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "HomeEditStep1",
                "EditStep1/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "EditStep1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                    new string[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" }
            );
```

the controller should be picked up from the route defaults, but you're not giving the RouteEngine any way to build your route, so it's technically using a default route, which I'm assuming you've removed (since we cannot see your entire routing "table")

Comment: The missing link!  Thanks!

Comment: glad to help... always takes just a second set of eyes :)